Missing text in dialog windows
So I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 and I am missing text in some of the dialog GNOME windows (see img). Some of it appears again if I hover over it with cursor or maximize the window.
Any idea what could be the issue?


Upvoted. Same issue here.

In my case, it looks like its an issue with the proprietary NVIDIA driver (commonly problematic with Ubuntu). Switching to the open-source X.Org driver seems to work.

I do run on x.org though

Found a solution by @george-panov
https://askubuntu.com/a/1511888/1800965
update /etc/environment
GSK_RENDERER=gl

and restart.

This is a dupe of the answer you point to.
